# Print elements of a list based on probabilities in for loop

Tags: python, list, for-loop, simulation, probability

Based on the probabilities of p, if p < 0.5 I would like to take letters of the corresponding positions of list1.

For example:

```
for i in range(5):
    list1 = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
    p = np.random.uniform(low= 0.0, high= 1.0, size=5)
    print(p)
```

Output is:

```
[ 0.46565909  0.741431    0.65590764  0.87347741  0.38465195]
[ 0.62172525  0.80688763  0.40391766  0.28042554  0.34544989]
[ 0.00138961  0.56959351  0.69043625  0.59473154  0.84042555]
[ 0.18535428  0.63470281  0.27882709  0.78731892  0.63624727]
[ 0.89383216  0.72008758  0.66048462  0.94064897  0.1484418 ]
```

So based on the probabilities I would like my output to be:

```
['A', 'E']
['C', 'D', 'E']
['A']
['A', 'C']
['E']
```

Comment: `if p < 0.5: print(list1[i])`?

Comment: well, probability mean that you will not have that output....but that you may have that output...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `np.where` to get the indices where the values are less than 0.5 and then print those elements:

```
for i in range(5):
    list1 = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
    mask = np.where(np.random.uniform(low= 0.0, high= 1.0, size=5) < 0.5)
    print([list1[i] for i in mask[0]])

#output (The output is stochastic meaning they will change on each iteration unless you use fixed random state)
['C']
['A', 'B', 'C', 'E']
['D', 'E']
['A', 'C', 'D']
['B', 'C', 'E']
```

Answer (score 1):

you can apply direct less than operator if you change your `list` to `numpy array`

```
for i in range(5):
    list1 = np.asarray(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'])
    p = np.random.uniform(low= 0.0, high= 1.0, size=5)
    print(list1[p < 0.5])
```

Out:

```
['C']
['A' 'D']
['A' 'B' 'C' 'D']
['A' 'B' 'E']
['A' 'B' 'D']
```

Answer (score 1):

Just another option:

```
[ [l for r, l in zip(np.random.uniform(low= 0.0, high= 1.0, size=5), list1) if r > 0.5] for i in range(5) ]

#=> [['A'], ['D', 'E'], ['B', 'C'], ['D'], ['B', 'C', 'E']]
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this is with np.where, as suggested in another answer here.

Alternatively, in the style of functional programming, filter the list of letters by a function that "tosses the coin", namely:

```
filter(lambda letter: np.random.uniform() < 0.5, list1)
```

Or, equivalently:

```
(letter for letter in list1 if np.random.uniform() < 0.5)
```